# What are the rules regarding question titles?

Tags: discussion, titles

[One of my recent questions, titled **☁ A Little Cloud ☁**](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/38093/little-chandler-is-sad-draw-him-a-cloud-to-cheer-him-up), was renamed in an edit to **Little Chandler is sad. Draw him a cloud to cheer him up**. I don't mind the title change, but I am curious as to the reasons why it was changed. Was it because of the Unicode characters? Or something else? I was hopeful to create a series of challenges based off Dubliners, but if there is something wrong about using the titles of the short stories as challenge titles, I would like to know.

In particular, is there a full set of rules or guidelines available for what sort of titles are allowed?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was due to the Unicode popping up on all sites (via HNQ). But the guy who changed it wasn't from PPCG but an SE dev/mod, so I think you're more likely to get an answer on meta.SE.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Since the issue is specific to [codegolf.se], it would be off-topic on [metase].

Comment: The use of exotic Unicode characters may be a problem because many people won't have the right fonts.

Comment: I [asked it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239869/is-unicode-in-hot-network-questions-question-titles-allowed) on Meta SE. I framed the question in regards to the HNQ to make it on-topic over there.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @Gilles Don't your two comments contradict each other? If it's an issue of installed fonts, how is that specific to PPCG and not the network as a whole? The fact that it's Sklivvz's only activity here for over 6 months suggests to me that it was only even edited because it showed up network-wide on HNQ.

Comment: @Geobits This meta question is about the specific renaming performed by Sklivvz, not about the use of Unicode in titles in general. Furthermore the wisdom of using certain characters in titles may vary between sites (for example, anyone interested in, say, [chinese.se] is assumed to have no trouble with Chinese characters, but this may not be the case for users who are only interested in [cooking.se]).

Comment: Even though the title was ostensibly changed to "be descriptive enough to make sense in any site", the new title is still fairly opaque. In general, please use [descriptive titles](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2119/click-here-to-find-out-what-this-question-is-about/2122#2122). Also, changing titles for HNQ is funny in light of the gaming.SE tradition to get deliberately disorienting titles onto HNQ, such as [Is it bad if all my kittens starve?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/184326/is-it-bad-if-all-my-kittens-starve)

Comment: I agree that the new title is not much more descriptive. In my opinion storytelling style like “Little Chandler is sad.” is acceptable in challenge description as it is kept short, but definitely not in titles.